# Why $Q_{t}=\frac{d g}{d p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{2 t} \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 k t}} g^{\prime}(p)$ is solution to diffusion equation?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

> Our purpose in this section is to solve the problem
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> u_{t} &=k u_{x x} \quad(-\infty<x<\infty, 0<t<\infty) \\
> u(x, 0) &=\phi(x) .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> We'll look for $Q(x, t)$ of the special form
> $$
> Q(x, t)=g(p) \quad \text { where } p=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 k t}}
> $$

> $$Q_{t}=\frac{d g}{d p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{2 t} \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 k t}} g^{\prime}(p)$$

Wolframalpha says that $$Q_{t}=-\frac{x g^{\prime}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{k t}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{k} t^{3 / 2}}$$

I think this is in contradiction to the reference calculation and I see no way to obtain the reference calculation.

Who is correct?

Comment: Are you sure these expressions differ? (Note that $\sqrt{4} = 2$, $\sqrt{t} = t^\frac12$ and $\rho = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$.)

Comment: $$t^{\dfrac{3}{2}}\neq t^{\dfrac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: But $t \cdot \sqrt{t} = t^\frac32$.